# CSS :first-child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

How come both links get bold with this setup?

I would like that only the a-tag just below the li.current get bold.

CSS

```
.ul li.current a:first-child{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Html

```
<ul>
  <li class="current">
    <a href="">This link</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="">Not this</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: remove the '.' before your ul first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
ul li.current > a:first-child{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DnvFR/)**

The `>` refers to the immediate child. So while your rule was being applied to any anchor that was a child, the above rule only applies to the immediate children of `ul li.current`. Note that you may also be able to drop the `:first-child` part depending on how you want your links formatted.

Also note that in your code you have `.ul` where you probably just wanted `ul` as is in my example.

Comment: Yup; both anchor tags were the 'first child' in their own contexts.

Answer (score 0):

If the website isn't that dynamic, you might be able to get away with adding `style="font-weight:bold"` to the `<a>` tag you want bold. This will also let you make any links you like bold whenever. It is outside of the style-sheet though.