# css how to only make bold fonts for first <ul> set

Tags: css

I have 2 or more `<UL>` sets inside, and wants to only make first UL `<a>` set to bold.
in fact, this is a menu with multiple sub menus, and I only want to make parent links bold.

I know it can be done by adding some more ID's or classes, but this is not an option, and just want to try css method only.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="collapsed first">
        <a title="Mechanical products" href="1">Mechanical Products</a>
    </li>
  <li class="collapsed">
    <a title="Chemicals" href="2">Chemicals</a>
  </li>
  <li class="expanded active-trail">
    <a title="Instrumentation" href="3">Instrumentation</a>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="leaf first">
            <a title="Control valves FISHER" href="4">Control Valves</a>
        </li>
      <li class="expanded active-trail">
        <a class="active" title="Corrosion Monitoring System" href="5">Corrosion Monitoring</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="leaf first">
                <a title="Access Fitting Assemblies" href="6">Fitting Assemblies</a>
            </li>
          <li class="leaf last">
            <a title="Coupon Holders, Coupons &amp; Probes" href="7">Holders,Coupons</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li class="collapsed">
        <a title="Mechanical products2" href="8">Mechanical Products2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

as of this example, only "Mechanical Products", "Chemicals", "Instrumentation" and "Mechanical Products2" should get bold.

Comment: Hi there's a post that could help you to get [an idea.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585773/css-first-child-selector)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the first child selector: `>`

```
.menu > li {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Not that if you need to support IE6, you'll have to do it manually, as IE6 doesn't support the `>` selector:

```
.menu li a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu li ul li a {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: The [`>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) is the child selector, not to be confused with the [`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) pseudo-class.

Comment: thanks. the second one is the answer for cross browsers. I almost forgot I could remove the second ul's bold attribute.

Comment: Please somebody create a virus to eradicate every running versions of IE6!

Answer (score 1):

It will probably do it...

```
ul.menu li a
{
    font-weight:bold;
}

ul.menu li ul li a
{
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the child selector and make the top-level `<ul>` unique by giving it some class:

```
ul.top-level > li > a {
   font-weight: bold;
}​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kJJw9/**

Comment: @HabibS: Only IE6 and below. I don't plan on wasting my time to support browsers that old.

Answer (score 0):

ul.menu li.collapsed a{font-weight:bold;}